# IOS:How to set file id in NSFileManager?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I have a json with

```
{
                        "FolderID": "17",
                        "FolderName": "Outdoor Look",
                        "MarkForDeletion": false,
                        "NewUpdateFolderID": null,
                        "ParentFolderID": "0"
                        },
                        {
                        "FolderID": "20",
                        "FolderName": "Sub 1",
                        "MarkForDeletion": false,
                        "NewUpdateFolderID": null,
                        "ParentFolderID": "17"
                        },
                        {
                        "FolderID": "22",
                        "FolderName": "Sub 2",
                        "MarkForDeletion": false,
                        "NewUpdateFolderID": null,
                        "ParentFolderID": "17"
                        },
```

when i creating files i want to set folder id to each directory  currently I was creating file like this

```
[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]stringByAppendingPathComponent:FolderName] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
```

how to pass the folder id value when i creating directory?

Comment: Your code creates directory, not files. What is a "file id" that you want to "set", which classes are you working with ?

Comment: @A-Live sorry i want to set the directory id

Comment: What is a directory id ?

Comment: @A-Live I updated my question.. I want to set folder id as a directory id

Comment: What is the purpose of the folder id?  If you could pass it, what would you want `createDirectoryAtPath` to do with it?

Comment: @PhillipMills Each folders I have set of images then only i need a folder id

Comment: @PhillipMills Also I want the folder id for  rename and delete the directory

Comment: I still don't understand your definition of directory identifier, is it something that you've made up for some kind of faster association or access ? If so, I believe you'd have to create your own filesystem manager that would use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any id field associated with directories that can be set.  If you want to use your id numbers, you should create your directory and then save its path or URL in your own dictionary with the FolderID as the key.

You can then store your dictionary in the user defaults and use the id to look up a matching path/URL which can be used for delete/rename....

To make it transparent, create a class that takes a FolderID and translates to something that the file manager can work with.